# How to extract record using multiple filter to Array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is a table like below on GoogleCloudBigquery.

```
id:1, arr_val: [{"a":"111"},{"a":"222"},{"a":"333"}]
id:2, arr_val: [{"a":"000"},{"a":"222"},{"a":"333"}]
id:2, arr_val: [{"a":"111"},{"a":"444"},{"a":"555"}]
...
```

I want to search record that has a {"a":111} and {"a":222}.

In the example above, I want that id1 be extracted.

I tried below

```
SELECT
  arr_val
FROM
  "TableName",
  UNNEST(arr_val) AS line
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(line.a, r"....") )
and
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(line.a, r"....") )
```

If WHERE condition is one condition, Query is works each.

But, It does not work well when WHERE condition is two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, arr_val
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM t.arr_val line WHERE a IN (111, 222))
```